# call actionfunction controller method before command button action method

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction

```
    <apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="PartnerRegController" docType="html-5.0" lightningStylesheets="true">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log("loaded");
    j$('input[type="submit"]').hide();
        var empty = false;
   j$('.requiredBlock input').each(function() {
       if (j$(this).val() == '') empty = true;
    });
    if (empty) {
    $('input[type="submit"]').hide();
     } else {
      $('input[type="submit"]').show();
    }
    });
});
})()
</script>  
 <script>
        function performCallOut()
        {
            if(hasMessages == 'false') {
                performCallOut();
            }
        }
    </script>    
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>
     <apex:messages id="msgId"/>
    <apex:form enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <apex:pageBlock id="block" >     
        <apex:messages rendered="true"/>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="User details" rendered="{!pb1}">
            <apex:outputField value="{!usr.Email}"  />
            <apex:outputField value="{!usr.firstname}"  />
            <apex:outputField value="{!usr.lastname}"  />
            <apex:inputField value="{!con2.Peildatum__c}" required="true" styleClass="form-control"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con2.BSN__c}" required="true" styleClass="form-control" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!con2.Contract__c}" required="true" styleClass="form-control"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Partner details" rendered="{!pb1}" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.Salutation}" styleClass="form-control"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.firstname}" styleClass="form-control"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.lastname}" styleClass="form-control"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.Email}" required="true" styleClass="form-control"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.Phone}" styleClass="form-control"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.MobilePhone}" styleClass="form-control"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.Birthdate}" styleClass="form-control"/>    
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.BSN__c}" required="true" styleClass="form-control"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.Peildatum__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.KoopsomTotaal__c}"  styleClass="form-control"/> 
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.uitvoeringsDatum__c}"  styleClass="form-control"/>
            <center>
            **<apex:actionFunction name="performCallout" action="{!connectionCall}" reRender="msgId,script-block"/>
                <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" action="{!renderPb2}" value="Next" oncomplete="return performCallout();" reRender="block,script-block" rendered="{!nextButton}"/>**
            </center>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>




        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Pension Calculation" rendered="{!pb2}"  >
            <apex:outputText label="Pension OP " value="{!pensionOP}" />
            <apex:outputText label="Pension NP " value="{!pensionNP}" />
            <apex:inputText label="Percentage of OP for share" value="{!percentagenOP}" />
            <apex:inputText label="Percentage of NP for share" value="{!percentagenNP}" />  
        </apex:pageBlockSection>   

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Upload Legal Document" columns="2" id="uploadBlock" rendered="{!pb2}">

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Document Name" for="fileName"/>
          <apex:inputText value="{!attachment.name}" id="fileName" required="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Attach Document" for="file"/>
          <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file" required="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Description" for="description"/>
          <apex:inputTextarea value="{!attachment.description}" id="description"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

      </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <center>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!renderPb1}" value="Prev" styleClass="btn btn-primary" reRender="block" rendered="{!prevButton}"/>
                <apex:commandButton id="submit"  value="Submit" styleClass="btn btn-primary" rendered="{!prevButton}" action="{!submitAction}" />
            </center>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

    <apex:outPutPanel layout="block" id="script-block">
        <script>
            var hasMessages = '{!hasError}';
        </script>
    </apex:outPutPanel>
</apex:page>
```

I want to call action function controller method before my command button action method onclick of my next button.

```
**<apex:actionFunction name="performCallout" action="{!connectionCall}" reRender="msgId,script-block"/>
                <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" action="{!renderPb2}" value="Next" oncomplete="return performCallout();" reRender="block,script-block" rendered="{!nextButton}"/>**
```

In a normal flow when i click on the button ,the action associated to the button is executed first and then my action function controller method is executed,
but i want when i click on the button ,i want my actionfunction to be executed first and then the method associated with the command button.

Comment: can you post only relevant code about your ask. Secondly, your question is not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @SantanuBoral I updated my question .Is it okay ?Shall i paste the controller too?

Comment: what is the purpose of calling actionfunction and then your controller action method?

Comment: On the actionfunction method ,I am making a call out then creating a record ,after that the button method is used to update the other related object .

Comment: You can use onclick javascript method of the button